# Cambiar el tiempo de ejecución de un hilo automáticamente en java

Tags: java, hilos

```
public void tiempo() {
    velocidad = (int) tabla.getValueAt(n, 1);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
```

//aqui iria el codigo

```
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, velocidad);
}
```

Ese es un pequeño ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando (No sirve claro esta) pero lo que busco es que dependiendo de los valores que velocidad este tomando el tiempo de ejecución también tome los valores es decir, por ejemplo si velocidad tiene el valor de 1 segundo, el tiempo de ejecución o de espera pase hacer de un segundo, luego si velocidad es 5 segundos, el tiempo de ejecución o de espera pase a ser 5 segundos, esto debe ser automáticamente hasta que velocidad tome un ultimo valor.

También mencionar que utilice recursividad y Thread.sleep, el problema es que como estoy trabajando con imágenes esta me utiliza es la ultima foto y no se muestran las anteriores a ella.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tus imports para asegurarnos que hablemos de lo mismo? De esa manera tendrías un [mcve]

Comment: import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

y velocidad la uso como variable global.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, te pregunté porque normalmente con intefaz gráfica se usa `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: Bien, yo no lo he usado, sino más bien la familia de los executors (que creo que es un framework que se integró allá por Java 5), por ejemplo `ScheduledThreadExecutor`, te recomiendo leer el libro http://jcip.net/, en él indican que Timer puede ser sensible a cambios en el reloj del sistema y que maneja un único hilo, lo que podría provocar demoras en otras tareas concurrentes, aunque podrías tener tus razones muy válidas para usarlo ( como una versión de Java muy vieja, cosa que no sabemos porque no lo especificaste ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que entendí de la documentación de Oracle no hay manera de cambiarle el tiempo a **scheduleAtFixedRate()** una vez que es creado. Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer para volver a crearlo cuando sea necesario. Probablemente haya una mejor forma de hacerlo, espero que te sirva para orientarte un poco aunque sea.

A.java

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class A {
    public Integer x = 100;
    public Timer t;
    public A a;
    public B b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.f(a);

    }
    public void f(A a) {
        a.t = new Timer();
        a.b = new B(a);
        // le agregué el segundo parámetro para que respete
        // el nuevo valor de 'x' antes de ejecutarse
        a.t.scheduleAtFixedRate(b, x, x);
    }
}
```

B.java

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class B extends TimerTask implements Runnable {
    public A a;
    public B(A a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(d.getMinutes() +":"+ d.getSeconds() + " Demora: " + (float)a.x/1000 +"s");
        a.x *= 2;

//      if(a.x != nuevoValor) vuelve a crear el "schedule" 
        a.t.cancel();
        a.t.purge();
        a.f(a); 
    }
}
```